# Camus - Writing to multiple file types

Tags: json, hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, camus

I am quite new to using LinkedIn's camus and have successfully written data files from Kafka to Hdfs.
In general, I use `JsonStringMessagdecoder` to read a JSON and write the same to `.dat` file using `StringRecordWriterProvider`.

But is it possible to write to multiple file types?

Suppose the json in `kafka` is as follows :

```
{ "user":"John", "message":"Hi how are you?" }
```

Now I want `John,Hi how are you?` to be written to one file, while `user,message` to be written to another file(`.meta`) in the same location. Is it possible ?